# How do I find out why I get anytime the same error message from an original Ubuntu script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, ram, swap, free

[Swap2Ram.sh](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) always produces its error message, even when I have enough ram left. Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/sh

mem=$(free  | awk '/Mem:/ {print $4}')
swap=$(free | awk '/Swap:/ {print $3}')

if [ $mem -lt $swap ]; then
    echo "ERROR: not enough RAM to write swap back, nothing done" >&2
    exit 1
fi

swapoff -a && 
swapon -a
```

I am on Linux 3.13.0-52-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.
Ubuntu Gnome.

**Update**
$ `LC_ALL=C free`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3841288    3161152     680136     149232      42076     424216
-/+ buffers/cache:    2694860    1146428
Swap:      3983356      35300    3948056
```

Comment: How do you know you have enough RAM left? Post an output of `free` for which you get this result.

Comment: Works for me. I'd suggest looking at the output of `free` (or adding a couple of echos) to see what's really going on.

Comment: @muru Gesamt Belegt(used) Frei(free) Gemeinsam Puffer Cache
(RAM)Speicher:    3841288    3109452     731836     210320      41844     483996
-/+ Puffer/Cache:    2583612    1257676
(Swap)Auslagerungsdatei:    3983356      35300    3948056

Comment: @brubaker just run `LC_ALL=C free` and [edit] your post to add the output. It might also be a localisation issue - the command searches for `Mem` and `Swap`, which may change depending on the locale.

Comment: @muru Damn! (I bet) your are right with the localisation issue.

Comment: @muru You were right and the first. Please submit an answer so I can accept your solution. TY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the script looks for `Mem` and `Swap`, whereas your localization produces `Speicher` and `Auslagerungsdatei`. Just add an `LC_ALL=C` before the `free`s in the script:

```
export LC_ALL=C
mem=$(free  | awk '/Mem:/ {print $4}')
swap=$(free | awk '/Swap:/ {print $3}')
```

Or:

```
mem=$(LC_ALL=C free  | awk '/Mem:/ {print $4}')
swap=$(LC_ALL=C free | awk '/Swap:/ {print $3}')
```

Comment: This is the new now working script, based on your solution:

#!/bin/sh

mem=$(free  | awk '/Speicher:/ {print $4}')
swap=$(free | awk '/Auslagerungsdatei:/ {print $3}')

if [ $mem -lt $swap ]; then
    echo "ERROR: not enough RAM to write swap back, nothing done" >&2
    exit 1
fi

swapoff -a &&
swapon -a

Comment: @brubaker I see you changed the strings instead. Just be careful if you ever change your locale.

Comment: I added "_de.sh" to the script name and did some comments inside. I edited the script seconds before your post. So I didn't saw your solution. :) But I am sure I got some bonus points for doing it myself. ;)

Comment: @brubaker setting the locale to `C`, since the behaviour with `C` is well known - and it will work even if your preferred locale changes.

Comment: I will change it like you proposed. TY again.